# How to check if Laravel request has no input

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

I would like to display a text only when my `request` does not contain any `input`s

At the moment, a product list is displayed on the following page: `/products`. On that same page, there is a form with several inputs to filter the products.

If I filter by price, I get the following URL once the GET form is submitted: `/products?price=true`

I am using the following condition to check if the request has a price input:  `if(Input::has('price'))`

This works fine, but I have several other request parameters, and I would like to display the text only when none of those inputs are filled.

This is what I have so far, it works, but it is not ideal:

```
@if(Input::has('price')||Input::has('mixed')||Input::has('male')||Input::has('female')||Input::has('kid')||Input::has('page'))
  //Do nothing
@else
  //Display my text here
@endif
```

Is there a way to do something similar but in much simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@if (!request()->filled('price') || !request()->filled('mixed') || !request()->filled('male') || !request()->filled('female'))
  // Display my text here
@endif
```

- Before Laravel 5.4:

  - `$request->exists`: Determine if the request contains a given input item key.
  - `$request->has`: Determine if the request contains a non-empty value for an input item.
- In Laravel 5.5:

  - `$request->exists`: Alias for $request->has
  - `$request->has`: Determine if the request contains a given input item key.
  - [`$request->filled`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L113-L1): Determine if the request contains a non-empty value for an input item.

Comment: Hi, Pimar. What will happen when I used $request->filled('fcm_token') and fcm_token not exist in $request.

Comment: @AssadYaqoob It will return `false`. You could use `whenFilled` instead, if your input is not always present in the form. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 11):

Get all input data, and count it:

```
@if ( ! count(Input::all()))
  // Display text here
@endif
```